# Real time data processing

Tags: performance, database-design, real-time

I am parsing keywords several times per second. Every second i have 1000 - 5000 keywords. So i want to find outlier, growing and other stuff which called technical analysis. One of the problem is how to store data. 
I will be able to do someting like:

```
         20-01 20-02 20-03 
brother    0      3     4
table      1      0     0
cup        34     54    78
```

But it might be a lot of keywords. For every new part of data i need to look is this word exists? If donnt then i must to add new words and add new rows for them. What is right way to organize store? Should i use key\value database, NoSQL or something else?

Comment: How many columns do you have? E.g. `20-01`, etc...

Comment: is this time series data and you are capturing keywords per second (and have to add new keywords previously not used)?

Comment: @the coon It's time series data that's why colums are added every time when program is working.

Comment: @Neir0: Then you better start looking at MongoDb first. I thought the columns set is static. In that case you need a document database.